# Ruby -- Why does += increase the number for my string?

Tags: ruby, string, dictionary, hash, counter

In the following code the value for `"seven"` changes from `1` to `2`:

```
word_counts = Hash.new(0)
sample = "If seven maids with seven mops"
sample.split.each do |word|
  word_counts[word.downcase] += 1
  puts word_counts
end
```

Output:

```
{}
{"if"=>1}
{"if"=>1, "seven"=>1}
{"if"=>1, "seven"=>1, "maids"=>1}
{"if"=>1, "seven"=>1, "maids"=>1, "with"=>1}
{"if"=>1, "seven"=>2, "maids"=>1, "with"=>1}
{"if"=>1, "seven"=>2, "maids"=>1, "with"=>1, "mops"=>1}
```

Can someone explain why it went from `1` to `2`?

Comment: Do you know what the `+=` operator does?

Comment: Try with `sample = "seven seven seven seven seven"`. Notice anything?

Comment: okay i am super stupid, i guess i didn't read that there was two "sevens" in the string. I just looked at the rest of the code assuming the initial string was all unique. thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'll try..

`word_counts[word.downcase] += 1` means `word_counts[word.downcase] = word_counts[word.downcase] + 1`. Now, on fifth iteration `word` equals `'seven'`, so it does `word_counts['seven'] = word_counts['seven'] + 1`. But `word_counts['seven']` was `1`, so it becomes `2`.

When you split the string you get the array with two strings `"seven"`, because the sentence has two occurrences of that word.

```
"If seven maids with seven mops".split #=> ["If", "seven", "maids", "with", "seven", "mops"]
```

Comment: okay i am super stupid, i guess i didn't read that there was two "sevens" in the string. I just looked at the rest of the code assuming the initial string was all unique. thanks. i got it

Comment: yeah i just got that, thanks so much. I was just so focused on thinking it was the code when it was actually just the string. got it!